# Compatibility problems when using 2.0.0 google-api-client for Gmail calls

Tags: java, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

I've been working on a little project that connects to the user's Gmail inbox and reads the mails using `google-api-client` 2.0.0 and `google-api-services-gmail` version v1-rev20220404-2.0.0

When I try to build the Gmail service

```
service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY,
          authorize).setApplicationName(Main.APPLICATION_NAME).build();
```

it throws an IllegalStateException that says

> "You are currently running with version 2.0.0 of google-api-client. You need at least version 1.15 of google-api-client to run version 1.25.0 of the Gmail API library."

At first I thought that maybe the modules I installed weren't up to date or something but it didn't really make sense, so I tried debugging and got in the Gmail.java class.

The code checks for the version in a really simple way, if the condition is false then it throws the exception

```
static {
        Preconditions.checkState(GoogleUtils.MAJOR_VERSION == 1 && GoogleUtils.MINOR_VERSION >= 15,
        "You are currently running with version %s of google-api-client. You need at least version 1.15 of google-api-client to run version 1.25.0 of the Gmail API library.",
        new Object[]{GoogleUtils.VERSION});
    }
```

This is where the problem lies I think, my MAJOR_VERSION being 2 and MINOR_VERSION being 0 makes the statement false, even if the version I'm using is the latest. I have no idea if it can be solved by downgrading the API version to a 1.XX, I'll try anyway, but do you know if I'm onto something here?

Comment: Little bonus: it works if I use version 1.35.2, wich means that it's probably a bug

Comment: Are you sure your using the [google apis java client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client) library and not the [google cloud java client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java) library?

Comment: Yes, I was using the client apis

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to upgrade to the v1-rev20230206-2.0.0
which is the latest version as of this writing

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
   <version>v1-rev20230206-2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/downloads#java) recommends searching for the lastest version [here](https://central.sonatype.com/?smo=true)

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone else, I encountered this error when upgrading the Firebase Admin plugin. It prevented my App Engine app from starting up.

A simple fix for me was to revert my POM file.

Fix: downgrade 9.1.1 to 8.1.0:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Dave B said.

If you visit Google's documentation site here, it will display the version of the client library. You will also find the link below to the Gmail library. I would advise against using third-party websites to obtain the package, as they may not contain accurate information. However, there is indeed a version 2 of the library that you may be looking for. Remember to watch out for fake libraries and always check for vulnerabilities in a library before incorporating it into your application. :)

https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-gmail/latest/

https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-api-client/latest/overview